# Create keybinding to focus master client in awesome-wm

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

I would like to create a keybinding to switch focus to the master client. Profjim on [this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=91245) notes:

> To get the master client on the current tag:
>
> ```
> c = awful.client.getmaster()
> ```

I have tried the following, but it causes my ~/.config/rc.lua file to be ignored, which is the behavior if there is an error in the file. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

```
awful.key({ modkey,          , "e",  awful.client.getMaster()),
```

Note: "e" shouldn't cause any conflicts if you have the default key bindings.

Edit: Someone on [/r/awesomewm](http://www.reddit.com/r/awesomewm/comments/1mz3jq/create_keybinding_to_focus_master_client_in/) knew the syntax to solve my problem:

```
awful.key({ modkey,          }, "e",  function() client.focus = awful.client.getmaster(); client.focus:raise() end),
```

Comment: Wow, the documentation is subtly horrid... (you are quite confused, but I don't blame you)

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the syntax errors; [from the documentation](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/index.html) it seems that [`awful.key`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.key.html) is a table, not a function. and it would presumably contain [`key`s](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/key.html#key)...which are hash tables, not sequences.

Finally your table syntax is wrong; a field may not be *syntactically* empty, it must have a listed value, even if that value is `nil`.

*So basically you are trying to pass the wrong kind of value to something that can't be called.*

---

As for how to do it correctly...the documentation is confusing, and apparently I'm not the only one that thinks so.

**deep breath**

okay, [`awful.new(...)`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/awful.key.html#new) *creates* key binders(?), and [`awful.key`](http://awesome.naquadah.org/doc/api/modules/key.html#key) *contains* key bindings, so clearly we have to put the results of the first into the second.
the code on your link is but a pointer, and only covers focusing the window, not creating a keybinding.

It *seems* like you want something like this:

```
function do_focus()
    current = client.focus
    master  = awful.client.getmaster()
    if current then
        client.focus = master
        master:raise()
    end
end

table.insert(awful.key, awful.new (modkey, 'e', nil, do_focus) )
```

*Bare in mind that I have no way of testing the above code.*

Comment: Nope. We just need [modal keybindings](http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Modal_Keybindings)